# Can't stop while loop with changed var from function

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I made an alarm which pops a window when timer is 0 this also starts a while loop for the sound so it keeps playing while the window is open. i however want it to stop when pressing a button. how can i use the changed value of a variable (done by button press) in a loop outside of the assignment?

i have been trying random different things and this is the latest version of my test file:

```
v = True


def Close():
    global root
    global v
    v = False
    root.destroy()
def Wdow():
    global root
    root = Tk()
    b = Button(root, text='OK', command=Close).grid()
    root.mainloop()

def Sound():

    global v
    while v:
        winsound.PlaySound('sound.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME)

def Pstart():
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        Process(target=Sound).start()
        Process(target=Wdow).start()

def Note():
    Pstart()
```

Comment: Where does `Process` come from? Is it from the `multiprocessing` module?

Comment: @FlorianWeimer yes its from that module.

Comment: I'm a little uncertain, but can you try to do all of your `global` declaring outside of all of your functions?

Comment: @MattCremeens that's definitely pointless. `global` statements in the global scope do nothing

Comment: @MattCremeens i had already tried that to no avail...

Comment: @BasVelden, apparently it's "pointless" anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `multiprocessing` requires a very special programming style.  You can [share state between processes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes), but it requires the use of the [`Value` class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Value) or a similar mechanism.  The usual Python variables will not work.

You also have to pass the `Value` object as an argument to the target function.  I cannot test this on Windows, but perhaps something like this will work:

```
def Wdow(v):
    global root
    root = Tk()
    def Close():
        global root
        v.value = 1
        root.destroy()
    b = Button(root, text='OK', command=Close).grid()
    root.mainloop()

def Sound(v):
    while v.value == 0:
        winsound.PlaySound('sound.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    v = multiprocessing.Value('i', 0)
    Process(target=Sound, args=(v,)).start()
    Process(target=Wdow, args=(v,)).start()
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Do you maybe know a better way of running the window function and sound loop at the same time so i could avoid this module?

Comment: I expect that threads and the `threading` module are a bit easier to use for things like, especially on Windows, but you will still have to be careful.

Comment: Perfect, this is much better to work with. Again thank you